# Argumentless lambdas in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

Is there a way to code:

```
def fn():
    return None
```

as a lambda, in Python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the argument list can be omitted:

```
fn = lambda: None
```

The production from [5.12. Lambdas](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is:

```
lambda_form     ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression
```

The square brackets around `parameter_list` indicate an optional element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
fn = lambda: None
```

Answer (score 0):

to be sure that works even with positional and kewyword arguments:

```python
fn = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
```